# Desarrollo en .net Compact (Smart Device)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en .NET Compact para Windows Embedded con lenguaje C# y base de datos SQL Compact 3.5.

La aplicacion tiene 3 columnas con varias filas, tengo 2 columnas que muestran en sus filas una información ya establecida en la base de datos y en la tercera columna iría lo que el usuario digita, esto va montado en un DataGrid en donde se llama la información de la base de datos, tengo un Textbox en donde se coloca la información que va en la tercera columna y dos botones uno para editar y otro para guardar.

Se presenta el siguiente problema:

Cuando yo quiero ejecutar desde el equipo donde estoy desarrollando, me sale un `error nativo 25009` que no me deja de pasar de la línea de abrir la base de datos, por otra parte cuando yo lo ejecuto en el dispositivo, éste me arroja un error de mapeo. Ya compruebo la ruta y la ruta de la base de datos es la correcta disco `C/Carpeta Base de datos` y dentro de ahí esta mi `base de datos .sdf`,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto el código fuente:

```
    private void btnEditar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridCell currentCell;
        string currentCellData;
        //  Se obtiene el texto a poner en la celda actual.
        currentCellData = txtCantidad.Text;
        //  Se obtiene la celda actual.
        currentCell = dtFrutas.CurrentCell;
        //  Se asigna la data a la celda actual.
        dtFrutas[currentCell.RowNumber, currentCell.ColumnNumber] = currentCellData;
        txtCantidad.Text = "";
    }


    private void btnGuardar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlCeConnection conn = null;
        //SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source =\"\\Program Files\\FrutayPastelino\\MisPedidos.sdf\";");
        SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source = C:\\Base de datos\\MisPedidos.sdf");
        //con.Open();
        SqlCeCommand ad = new SqlCeCommand("UPDATE Fruta SET Cantidad = @cantidad WHERE Codigo_Integra = @codigo_integra", con);
        con.Open(); // Error nativo 25009 en el ordenador.

        try
        {
           ad.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cantidad",txtCantidad.Text);
           ad.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codigo_integra", " ");   //ERROR DE MAPEO EN EL DISPOSITIVO
           //ad.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Pedido bien");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {  
            con.Close();
            ad.Dispose();
        }
    }


    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: esta línea de código carga datos en la tabla 'misPedidosDataSet.Fruta' Puede moverla o quitarla según sea necesario.
        this.frutaTableAdapter.Fill(this.misPedidosDataSet.Fruta);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Coloca el siguiente código en el btnGuardar y actualiza tu cadena de conexión.

```
string ruta;
ruta = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase);
MessageBox.Show(ruta);
```

Por otro lado, cuando hagas debugging de tu aplicación en tu dispositivo/emulador, revisa y verifica que la propiedad `Copy to Output Directory of your .sdf file` tenga el valor adecuado, así no se sobreescribirá la siguiente vez.

En ese `MessageBox` se encuentra el lugar donde se ejecuta tu programa, lo que nos da la ruta adecuada. Hasta donde estuve investigando en los `PocketPC` las rutas no tienen letras y toda ruta inicia con doble backslash \ por lo que mencionas del error nuevo, parece que la base de datos está en el lugar adecuado, sin embargo, por lo visto, el "código integra" debe ser numérico y como le estás asignando un campo vacío, lanza el error.

Lo que debe ir en el "código integra" es el ID de la fruta que vas a actualizar.

```
 UPDATE Fruta SET Cantidad = @cantidad WHERE Codigo_Integra = @codigo_integra
```

Esto quiere decir: actualizamos la tabla Fruta, el nuevo valor del campo `@Cantidad` será lo que hay en la variable `cantidad`, esto se aplica para todos los elementos que cumplen la condición: `Codigo_Integra` (campo de la tabla Frutas) es igual a `@codigo_integra` (el valor que le asignas).

Revisa la información de la grilla, te aseguro que ahí se encuentra el ID único (código_integra) que necesitas para actualizar la cantidad de la fruta :D y en caso exista, guárdala temporalmente en un textbox oculto y en cada actualización limpias ese textbox para evitar que se mezclen las cantidades con otros productos.

En caso que falte el ID de la grilla, revisa la consulta SQL y agrega ese ID faltante (codigo_integra), luego la puedes ocultar a la vista, pero el dato ya estará presente

Comment: Ahi es donde radica principalmente mi problema por que no dice en ningun lado conocido por mi donde me diga como es el id de esa grilla, ya que el datagrid no me lo muestra por grillas si no el cuadro completo.

Comment: La verdad creo que entiendo el problema es que no se como hacerlo, no se por donde empezar o que hacer la verdad

Comment: muchas gracias, eso me ayudaria mucho por que la verdad entiendo muy poco lo explicado

Comment: excelente! mientras tanto :D ahora puedes entrar a la sala http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol

Answer (score 0):

Intenta cambiar esta linea

```
SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source = C:\\Base de datos\\MisPedidos.sdf");
                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Por

```
SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source = C:\Base de datos\MisPedidos.sdf");
                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Otro tip, es que no dejes espacios en blanco en el path, por ejemplo `"Base de datos"`, yo recomendaría usar algo mas compacto como: `C:\bd\pedidos.sdf`

**Editado**

Presiamente me ocurrió lo mismo y me dí cuenta que todo el tiempo estuve poniendo mal direccionado el archivo .sdf

```
            using (var cnn = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source=MyData.sdf;Persist Security Info=False;"))
        {
            var command = new SqlCeCommand("update...", cnn);
            command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", "valor3");
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", "valor2");

            try
            {
                cnn.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

Comment: ya se hizo eso y el mismo resultado

Comment: Edite mi comentario anterior.

Comment: ya hice eso tambien y el problema sigue