# Solucionar Error nativo 25009

Tags: sql-server

Pues me sale ese error cuando se trata de abrir la base de datos, ya comprobo la ruta y la ruta de la base de datos es la correcta disco C/Carpeta Base de datos y dentro de ahi esta mi base de datos .sdf,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como lo puedo solucionar gracias

Comment: ¿Estás seguro de que la ruta de la base de datos está correctamente colocada?

Comment: Si muy seguro C:\Base de datos\MisPedidos y en la consulto coloco asi : SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source = C:\\Base de datos\\MisPedidos.sdf");

Comment: En dónde estás implementando ese proyecto?

Comment: Es un proyecto .net compact con sql compact 3.5, con planilla smart device

Comment: Por favor, actualice su pregunta con el fragmento de código fuente que está generando el error. La respuesta de fredyfx parece correcta.

Comment: He modificado tu pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/16682/desarrollo-en-net-compact-smart-device/17058 con la información mostrada aquí. La razón es que la otra (duplicada) es más completa y se entiende mejor.

Answer (score 0):

Dale un @ antes de las comillas:

```
System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection con = new System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=C:\Base de datos\MisPedidos.sdf");
```

**Actualización:**

Ya que estas utilizando un `smart device` asumo que con `Windows CE`, dicho sistema operativo requiere que toda ruta comience con un backslash "`\`"

Vamos actualizando la cadena de conexión:

```
System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection con = new System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=\\Base de datos\\MisPedidos.sdf");
```

Referencia: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20229175/3613462

Comment: Mismo resultado

Comment: Crea una carpeta dentro del C:\ con el nombre del proyecto, dale permisos de escritura y dentro de ella estaría la BD, intenta con esto :D

Comment: Mismo resultado

Comment: respuesta actualizada

Comment: pues la verdad me sigue dando el mismo error